# Can my Canon Eos camera be used with continuous power?

Tags: canon, dslr, power-supply

I have a Canon Eos 1100d camera. I am wondering if there is a method to use this camera without a battery, and connect to continuous power? I want to keep this camera open for a lot of days without charging the battery. It is possible?

Comment: Note that if you intend to keep the camera 'recording' for a long time, the sensor can overheat and shut down the camera. Very long exposure times or extended video recordings can cause this. 

Also note that the FAT-32 file system limits video record time to 4GB file size, which is about 30 mins of recording time, depending on quality. It is likely your camera will likely overheat or the file will hit maximum size before your batteries run out.

On the other hand, power for very long extended time lapses would be a very nice thing to have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this:

[Canon ACK E10 Adapter Kit](http://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/ac-adapter-kit-ack-e10)

[image: Canon ACK E10 Adapter]

Comment: I realize that my answers are always very synthetic :)

Answer (score 5):

Canon makes AC adapters for pretty much all of their cameras, but they can be a bit expensive.  In your particular case, the [Canon ACK E10](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=ACK-E10&N=0&InitialSearch=yes&sts=ma&Top+Nav-Search=) is the AC adapter for your camera.  This will provide continuous power to your camera, but it is also $65.  Third party options can be cheaper, but make sure you get a reputable one if you do so as to avoid damaging the camera.

It typically runs up in to the battery compartment through a little cover that can allow the cable to pass through and takes the place of the battery.

Answer (score -1):

I've also found a solution around $5 to produce this permanent power supply (kind a battery simulator) using the 7808 voltage regulator build into a battery package.

Here is the [YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/I-1xfSU5mDU)

Comment: Hi Trevor, welcome to Photo.SE! Please [do not post answers that consists essentially of a link](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please summarize the information you present in the video.