# How can I increase the battery life of my SLR?

Tags: power-supply

Do any of the camera manufacturers manufacture a power supply that lasts longer than the normal battery?  The battery in my Canon 70D limits me to approximately 4.5 hours of operation before the battery runs out, and I am not able to get the number of time lapse frames that I need in that duration.

Comment: What duration do you need?

Comment: What kind of portability do you need?

Comment: Did you consider to use a a battery grip with a second battery? Its a easy way to double the operation time.

Comment: What kind of settings are you using to shoot your timelapse? My 30D will easily last the 8 hours if you're say, taking one photo a minute. It'll probably do twice that if I'm careful and turn the LCD off and don't use the flash at all. I'd assume the 70D's battery life would be as good or better.

Comment: I am taking 17 second photos with a 6 second interval between photos at ISO 1000 (in this case).  I do think that 70d runs at slightly higher power, but I did not check to ensure that other things were turned off such as the wireless transmitter and I think I could have saved time if the screen settings were turned off.

Answer (score 6):

Canon (and every other manufacturer) make AC adapters for their cameras. If that's an option, your problem is solved - see [Can my Canon Eos camera be used with continuous power?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42999/can-my-canon-eos-camera-be-used-with-continuous-power) for a bit more detail.

If AC power isn't an option, are you using a grip? These contain a space for an extra battery so should double your available time.

Comment: Thank you for teh response.  I am looking to get about 8 hours of shooting, which the grip you mentioned would be capable of.

Comment: I should mention that there are a number of cheaper battery grips out there than the official ones - which tend to be rather expensive. I've ebay'd grips before and while they tend to be more plasticky and less nice, I can live with them.